# How to compensate integral anti-windup in PID temperature controller with current limiter?

Tags: control, pid, driver, current

I have a PID temperature controller that outputs a voltage to heat the system up and I would like to add current limiter as I assume I don't know the resistance of the heater.

The PID controller has already its saturation block connected to integral anti-windup block, conditional anti windup. When current is limited with its limit, I would like to somehow eliminate the integral windup.

How to do it? I'd be glad if there is a documentation of it as I know TEC temperature controllers has current limiter.

Comment: Can you give more details about the implementation you are using? What are the details of this antiwindup block that you referred to?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* grxty_, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I know sometimes it's possible to get deep into a problem, and when you try to communicate with others there's an assumption that they're as familiar with the project as you are. It's important to add details here so someone that isn't familiar with your problem can help out. You're mentioning an anti-windup block; is this in Matlab? Simulink? Simscape Electrical? You're also asking about current as if it's significantly different than voltage, but they should be proportional (V=IR). For `documentation of it`, do you mean the controller, windup block, device, or something else?